# How can I collect a list of all my iOS applications programmatically over the Internet?

Tags: ios, itunes

I would like to collect all the iOS apps I have on my iTunes account programmatically via a web script, applet or anything possible over the web. Idea is to have a web page where I can enter my iTunes credentials and then display all these apps.

It looks like no open API is offered by Apple to do this so what's the best way to do it?

The only way I can think of is an applet reading the XML files in the iTunes directory on my computer, but it's a poor solution regarding me for a few reasons.

EDIT : solution must be valid for any user (not only an iOS developer)

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this. I am also looking for an exact feature. I want to query the list of purchases made by a user and then filter out the purchases that points out to the apps developed by me.

Comment: unfortunately not. Haven't pushed my research since then though. If you find anything please share it here :)

Comment: could you provide any idea about the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425657/query-the-list-of-purchase-history-of-apps

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [iTunes Store Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) to search for apps by your developer name, then filter the results by your developer ID in case anyone has a similar name.

Comment: I edited the question to point the fact that I'd like a generic solution for any kind of users

Comment: Oh, you're wanting to query the apps a particular user has purchased?

Comment: Yes, exactly ! With its authorization of course since I ask for his credentials.

Answer (score 0):

It may interest you: http://www.apple.com/itunesaffiliates/API/AffiliatesSearch2.1.pdf

It's a document about iTunes Store Search API. It could be a starting-point.

Comment: I already checked this out and AFAIK it's only for affiliation programs which I'm not interested in here. But thx ;)