# Query the list of Purchase History of Apps

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, app-store

I have developed few apps which are live on appstore. Now I want to develop a main app which would comprise the existing apps which are on store as in-App purchases along with other items as in-App purchases as well.

**Explanation**:

1. I have published 5 lessons as standalone apps on AppStore.Lets say the name is a, b, c, d,e
2. I want to create a Main App "MAIN" which would comprise of various courses and these courses would comprise of lessons which include (but not limited to) a,b,c,d,e as well. These lessons would be available as inapp purchases.
3. I want to give the lessons free of cost for those users who have purchased my previous apps a,b,c,d or e. For eg: If a user has purchased apps a,b and c and now he downloads "Main". Then in the "Main", the lessons a,b,and c would be enabled without any in app purchase charge.
4. Initially I thought of canOpenURL/url schemes methodology in which I would query whether the a,b,c,d,or e exists via the Main App. If any/all of the apps exists then the lessons corresponding to those apps would be available as free download in the Main App. I implemented the same which is working fine during testing.
5. The problem in canOpenURl is that it is device specific. What if a user installs a,b and c on iPhone 5 and installs Main App on iPad. How would I get to know whether the user has installed a,b and c via Main App in this case?
6. My restriction is that I cannot ask for emails, passwords or any sort of unique identifier from the user.
7. Is it possible to query the purchase history of Apps (not In-App Purchases) so that I can filter the apps purchased by user which are developed by me ? Obviously if would pass through by asking the user to give their Apple-IDs. I understand that but is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your main app you ask your users who possess a,b,c,d,e to install them once in order to unlock the corresponding lessons in main.
You use canOpenURL on Main's launch to check if a,b,c,d,e is there and if that's the case you unlock the lesson and set a flag in Main to remember this.

This is far from perfect and is just a minor improvement to what you suggested but I've nothing else in mind as of now since you can't use any username or accounts to uniquely identify your users.

Comment: if you read my question again, the pointer 4 and 5 mentions about the same. I have already tested the same but being a device specific solution, it may not be acceptable as a long term solution.